# How do I detect a keydown event that will include the two Mac 'delete' key variations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, event-handling

My app has a textarea. Above that is a 'save' button that responds to any keydown event in the textarea by changing its background-color to alert the user to 'save' the edited text to the database by clicking that button.

```
$(".panelText").on("keydown","textarea",function() { 
    console.log("Keydown in textarea!");
    var textID=$(this).closest('.text').attr('id');  
    $('#'+textID).find('.saveText').addClass('textChanged');
});
```

It seems Mac/Safari is not producing a 'keydown' or 'keypress' event when either of the two Mac 'delete' key variations are pressed. When I run Chrome on the Mac it works fine for both 'keydown' or 'keypress' just as it does on whatever browser I test on Win10 systems. On Mac/Safari and other tested browsers all other keys that could change the text do fire for either 'keydown' or 'keypress'.

I discovered this after purchasing a refurbished Mac osx system to test my app on Apple devices, esp. with Safari since I believe a lot of users run that browser. I'm pretty unfamiliar with the Mac world. But if I'm correct that the event is not being fired for those two keys on Safari, how can I make this work in both worlds?

Edit/added 9/27 abt 10:00 AM

I found a very useful website for working with kbd events on various platforms, browsers and OS's. https://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Using this I found that on my Mac OSX/Safari platform, the

(backspace) delete key produces: 'keydown' event, keyCode:8, charCode:0 
and the delete key produces: 'keydown' event, keyCode:46, charCode:0

So, it seems the 'keydown' event is being fired for both delete keys but my app is not seeing it for some reason, as Daniel suggested below. Perhaps my app is somehow blocking the event but only on the Mac/Safari platform. And the fiddle app is not blocking it on either platform. I think I'll just have to start eliminating parts of my app until I isolate the problem.

Comment: Working fine for me with a simple example of `$("#test").on("keydown", function(e) { console.log(e); });`.  (Where "test" is a textarea with id "test".)  What version of Safari are you using?

Comment: It says I'm using Safari 11.1 on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Comment: Can you publish a snippet/fiddle/whatever of the full problem?  It's possible that there is some other issue affecting you.

Comment: I did a fiddle yesterday on both the Mac and my Win10 system and could not replicate the problem on either device. https://jsfiddle.net/banjobum/z6kkyfzf/

Comment: Sorry, wrong fiddle. Will post correction soon.

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/banjobum/z6kkyfzf/21/

Comment: This fiddle works for me, using a laptop keyboard as well as using a plugged-in keyboard with separate Backspace and Delete keys.  Safari 11.0.3.

Comment: Yes, I also could not replicate the problem with a fiddle - on Mac or Win10. I have further experimented and verified that the single problem running the full app on Safari/Mac is that the 'save' key changes background color correctly for all keypresses in the textarea except for the two delete keys on my Mac full desktop kbd. The delete action works correctly. But the 'save' button is not affected as it should be. If you or anyone wishes to see this mssg me and I'll send you a password to the app. Or we could use chat.

Answer (score 0):

Just try keyup

```
$(".panelText").on("keyup","textarea",function() { 
    console.log("Keydown in textarea!");
    var textID=$(this).closest('.text').attr('id');  
    $('#'+textID).find('.saveText').addClass('textChanged');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the same problem persists.